# Why is Wordpress so slow on my EC2 Server

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I have a **AWS EC2 nano** server with 0.5 GB memory and ARM 1 GB CPU with 2 cores.
It only has UBUNTU 22.04, NGINX 1.20 with LetsEncrypt and MariaDB installed.

I conducted serveral tests and, in order to process the following situations, I installed each of the following - **IN TURN**:

- first on clean: Node.js 16.16 LTS (running from PM2 on **JUST ONE CORE**)
- then also on clean: PHP 8.1 (PHP-FPM)
- then over PHP 8.1 (PHP-FPM): a clean Wordpress 6.0.1 without any plugins only with Twenty Twenty-Two theme

For NODEJS and simple PHP I put up a mockup simple page with a DB query, while for WORDPRESS I just tested the homepage. For all of them, the NGINX cache was off.

I have done several tests with **loader.io** with the following results:

1. STATIC FILE: ~ 6.000 requests/second
2. NODEJS: ~ 3.000 requests/second
3. PHP (SIMPLE): 1.500 requests/second
4. PHP WITH WORDPRESS: ~ 15 requests/second

Note: it is possible for PHP to do more optimizations like OPCache etc.

> So, is it something with my config or WP is so slow indeed?

From what I have seen online, they are suggesting to use NGINX as a cache in order to avoid the load, or even CloudFlare. It seems to work fine if you have just a blog, but what if the websites require dynamic content all the time, with user interaction, like Woocommerce etc.?

> Is there other option to make WP quicker other then cache the pages with NGINX?

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Can you offload the SSL to your Application Load Balancer? That is, if you are willing to pay for it.

Also, since you are using a nano server, may I suggest utilizing the [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) and user `t2.micro` EC2 coupled with a RDS. That should smoothen things up.

Also, have you tried removing your theme and/or reverting to the default theme and then observing?

You could also consider tuning some of your kernel parameters like:

`vm.swappiness`, `fs.file-max`, `net.core.somaxconn`, `net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range`, `net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse`, `net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_time_wait`, `net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout`

You can learn more about [kernel tuning here](https://hostingultraso.com/help/ubuntu/tuning-tcp-stack-ubuntu) or you could just search the web.

Comment: Hi @Shammi Shailay! Thanks for your quick reply. I think in all of the above situations the ratio between WP and the others will remain almost the same. But you made me think if there is a miminum requirements by WP in terms of memory and CPU. I will give it a shot on a more powerful instance on AWS. Yet, I have made the other days some tests on a machine of another hoster (CPU 16 cores and 64GB of memory) and the ratio of the results were quite the same.